# Printing as a 1 d array rather than 2 -dimensional array

Tags: c++, matrix, 2d

Can anyone tell me why this is printing as a 1-d array rather than a 2 -d? Nevermind im an idiot.

```
    int colls = 5;
  int rows  = 4;
  int array[rows][colls];

  for (int x=0; x < rows; x++)
  {
      for (int g=0; g < colls; g++)
      {

          array[x][g]=0;
          cout <<array[x][g];

      }

  }
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it? (i.e. what part of your code tries to make it print as a 2d array?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your array dimensions must be "const".  Secondly you need a endline at the end of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (int x=0; x < rows; x++) 
  { 
      for (int g=0; g < colls; g++) 
      { 

          array[x][g]=0; 
          cout <<array[x][g]; 

      } 
      cout << endl;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't print a new line after each row:

```
int colls = 5;
int rows  = 4;
int array[rows][colls];

for (int x=0; x < rows; x++)
{
    for (int g=0; g < colls; g++)
    {

        array[x][g]=0;
        cout <<array[x][g];

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not printing newline after printing all elements of a row.

Try this:

```
for (int x=0; x < rows; x++)
{
   for (int g=0; g < colls; g++)
   {
        array[x][g]=0;
        cout <<array[x][g];
    }
    cout << endl; //prints newline
}
```

By the way, it seems you've written `using namespace std` in your code. This brings all names from the namespace `std` to the current namespace which is considered a good practice. So I suggest you to remove this line (if you've written this):

```
using namespace std; //remove this line from your code.
```

And then use `std::cout` instead of `cout`, and `std::endl` instead of `endl`.

Similarly, use`std::` with all other names from the namespace `std`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to print `endl` after each row, which would be after the `colls` loop, i.e. after each iteration of the `rows` loop.